# Spring Boot Embedded ActiveMQ durable messages

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

In my Spring Boot application I have configured Embedded Apache ActiveMQ.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class ActiveMQConfig {

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new ActiveMQQueue("import.decisions.queue");
    }

}
```

In order to send the messages I use the following code:

```
@Autowired
private JmsMessagingTemplate jmsMessagingTemplate;

@Autowired
private Queue queue;

this.jmsMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(this.queue, message);
```

Right now I use in-memory ActiveMQ, this is my `application.properties`:

```
#ActiveMQ
spring.activemq.in-memory=true
spring.activemq.pool.enabled=false
spring.activemq.packages.trust-all=true
```

Because I don't want to lose the messages that was already enqueued, for example during the application restarts I need to configure my Embedded ActiveMQ to persist the data.

Could you please show how it can be done with Spring Boot configuration ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BrokerService by default is persistent, have you done some tests ?

if you want you can define it to override :

```
@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
    final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    //broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
    broker.addConnector("vm://localhost");
    PersistenceAdapter persistenceAdapter = new KahaDBPersistenceAdapter();
    File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "kaha");
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    persistenceAdapter.setDirectory(dir);
    broker.setPersistenceAdapter(persistenceAdapter);
    broker.setPersistent(true);
    return broker;
}
```

or

```
@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
    final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    //broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
    broker.addConnector("vm://localhost");
    broker.setPersistent(true);
    // default messages store is under AMQ_HOME/data/KahaDB/
    return broker;
}
```

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
>   <artifactId>activemq-kahadb-store</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added ~1000 messages into the queue. Then during the execution I have terminated my application and then started it one more time. After successful start nothing happens. The consumer doesn't consume the messages that were previously enqueued. Also, in order to test your approach with overridden broker service I can't find `KahaDBPersistenceAdapter` class in the application classpath. Right now I have only added `spring-boot-starter-activemq` into my Maven `pom.xml` in order to get ActiveMQ up and running. What other artifacts should be added also ?

Comment: sorry i forgot the mvn dependency, i have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, I have added activemq-kahadb-store and now the approach is start working!